# how get values from subview(UILabel) of ScrollView in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uilabel

i added 10 labels(labels contains  some data) to scrollview .i want to get the value of label at particular location .can u please get me know how to get the value at that location.please give suggestion for this is the code what i have written .how can i get the value of the user selected language

```
-(void)printLanguage
 {
    NSLog(@"in print language method");

    //int y=0;
   //NSMutableArray *languageArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Chinese",@"Spanish",@"English",@"Arabic",@"Hindi",@"Bengali",@"Portuguese",@"Russian",@"Japanese",@"German",nil];
  //UILabel *languageLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y ,90,30 )];

  languagValue=0;

  int y=0;
  NSMutableArray *languageArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Chinese",@"Spanish",@"English",@"Arabic",@"Hindi",@"Bengali",@"Portuguese",@"Russian",@"Japanese",@"German",nil]; 


for(languagValue=0;languagValue<[languageArray count];languagValue++)
{
    UILabel *languageLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y ,90,30 )];
    NSLog(@"array count is @%d",[languageArray count]);
    languageLabel.text=[languageArray objectAtIndex:languagValue];
    NSLog(@"array objectat index is @%@",[languageArray objectAtIndex:languagValue]);
    languageLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:19.0];
    languageLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [languageScrollView addSubview:languageLabel];
    //  [languageScrollView addSubview:languageLabel];
    //y+=90;        
    y+=languageLabel.frame.size.height;
    [languageLabel release];

}   

   [languageScrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
   [languageScrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
   [languageScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(genderScrollView.frame.size.width, y)];

}
```

Thank You,

girish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UILabel is not interactive component Girish. So you cannot get the event of its selection. Better use UIButtons. 
I have edited your code and added one method. Just make the languageArray global and the code whould work fine.

```
-(void)youMethod
{
    //int y=0;
    //NSMutableArray *languageArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Chinese",@"Spanish",@"English",@"Arabic",@"Hindi",@"Bengali",@"Portuguese",@"Russian",@"Japanese",@"German",nil];
    //UILabel *languageLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y ,90,30 )];

    languagValue=0;

    int y=0;
    NSMutableArray *languageArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Chinese",@"Spanish",@"English",@"Arabic",@"Hindi",@"Bengali",@"Portuguese",@"Russian",@"Japanese",@"German",nil]; 


    for(languagValue=0;languagValue<[languageArray count];languagValue++)
    {
         UILabel *languageLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y ,90,30 )];
         UIButton * btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
         btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, y ,90,30 );
         btn.tag = languagValue;
         [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(languageSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         NSLog(@"array count is @%d",[languageArray count]);
         languageLabel.text=[languageArray objectAtIndex:languagValue];
         NSLog(@"array objectat index is @%@",[languageArray objectAtIndex:languagValue]);
         languageLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:19.0];
         languageLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
         [languageScrollView addSubview:languageLabel];
         [languageScrollView addSubview:btn];
         //  [languageScrollView addSubview:languageLabel];
         //y+=90;        
         y+=languageLabel.frame.size.height;
         [languageLabel release];

         }   
         [languageScrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
         [languageScrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];

         [languageScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(genderScrollView.frame.size.width, y)];

}

-(void)languageSelected:(id)sender
{
    UIButton * btn = (UIButton*)sender;
    int selectedIndex = btn.tag;
    NSString * selectedLanguage = [languageArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Somebody must have set those values, wasn't it you ? :) Why would you ask labels for their values when you already must know it to set it in the first place.

EDIT : seeing your code, you probably can figure out from the `contentOffset` of the scroll view, but it seems that you'd be better off with a `UIPicker` or a `UITableView` where all this infrastructure is provided for free

Comment: i will show my code can u explain me what i have to get the values of that particular userselected value